# Convert python byte in string format to byte array in c#

Tags: c#, python, byte

In my python code i have a value in byte code, whenever print that byte code it will give something like this,

```
b'\xe0\xb6\x9c\xe0\xb7\x92\xe0\xb6\xb1\xe0\xb7\x8a\xe0\xb6\xaf\xe0\xb6\xbb'
```

now, that value in string format in c# that is,

```
string byteString = "b'\xe0\xb6\x9c\xe0\xb7\x92\xe0\xb6\xb1\xe0\xb7\x8a\xe0\xb6\xaf\xe0\xb6\xbb'";
```

so question is how can i convert that byteString to byte array in c#

but, my actual problem is i have a string value in python which is not in English, when i run the python code it will print the string(in non English, work fine). 
But, whenever run that python code in c# from process class it work fine for English and i can get the value. but it not working for non English characters, it was a null value. therefore, in python if i print that non English value in byte code i can get the value in c#. problem is how can i convert that in byte code into   byte array in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to modify your string slightly for usage in C#.

```
var str = "\xe0\xb6\x9c\xe0\xb7\x92\xe0\xb6\xb1\xe0\xb7\x8a\xe0\xb6\xaf\xe0\xb6\xbb";
```

You can then get your bytes fairly easily with LINQ.

```
var bytes = str.Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x)).ToArray();
```

An odd case that can occur with trying to use byte strings between Python and C# is that python will sometimes put out straight ASCII characters for certain byte values, leaving you with a mixed string like `b'\xe0ello'`. C# recognizes `\x##`, but it also attempts to parse `\x####`, which will tend to break when dealing with the output of a python bytestring that mixes hex codes and ascii.